# Zero dimensional quotient of a local Noetherian ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, local-rings, artinian

Let $(R,m)$ be a local Noetherian integral domain.
Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$, so $I \subseteq m$.

Then $R/I$ is also a local Noetherian ring, [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063196/quotient-ring-local-if-ring-is-local) (and the image of any surjective ring homomorphism of a Noetherian ring is Noetherian). But in order to be an integral domain,
$I$ must be a prime ideal of $R$, and this is not assumed.

Then unique maximal ideal of $R/I$ is $m/I$.

Also recall that a zero-dimensional Noetherian ring is Artinian, Lemma [10.60.4.](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00KD),
so $R/I$ is artinian.

Assume that the Krull dimension of $R/I$ is zero, $\dim(R/I)=0$. By the result mentioned (and proved) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806764/local-ring-of-krull-dimension-zero), there exists $n \geq 1$ such that $(m/I)^n=\bar{0}$. This means that there exists $n \geq 1$ such that $m^n \subseteq I$.

> **Question:** $m \supseteq I$, but powers of $m$ may not contain $I$, so we are not able to talk about a decreasing chain of ideals $(m/I) \supseteq (m/I)^2 \supseteq (m/I)^3 \cdots$? So perhaps if, for example, $m^2$ does not contain $I$, then we have $m/I=\bar{0}$ (namely, $m=I$)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: $(m/I)^n=(m^n+I)/I$

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful about how you define $(m/I)^n$. This does not correspond to $m^n$.

Now by definition

$$ (m/I)^n = \{\sum a_1 \cdot ... \cdot a_n | a_1, \dots , a_n \in m/I\}$$

To see what ideal of $R$ this corresponds to, just take the preimage and we see that the ideal in $R$ is going to be $I + m^n$ (since the ideal in $R/I$ contains zero, the preimage contains all of $I$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I have asked something else, maybe I should have explained more clearly. I know that $(m/I)^n=m^n+I$.

Comment: Yes it does. If $m^2$ does not contain $I$, you have that $(m/I)^2$ corresponds to $(m^2 + I)$ which is not necessarily a subset of $I$ (so $(m/I)^2$ is not necessarily the zero ideal). Note that when you use the right definition, you *do* get a descending chain of ideals $(m/I) \supseteq (m/I)^2 \supseteq ...$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So anyway, $m+I \supseteq m^2+I \supseteq m^3+I \supseteq \cdots I$, so $\frac{m+I}{I} \supseteq \frac{m^2+I}{I} \supseteq \frac{m^3+I}{I} \supseteq \cdots \bar{0}=\frac{I}{I}$ is a legitimate descending chain in $R/I$.